# Why doesn't this loop detect null pointer?

Tags: c++, null, nullpointerexception

So this is my code:

```
while(node) {
    cout<<node->getDiameter();
    node=node->stepAbove();
}
```

these are the methods:

```
Node* Node::stepAbove() {
    return this->above;
}
int Node::getDiameter() {
    return this->r;
}
```

but the while loop causes the Access Violation, because the loop doesn't detect a null pointer. When debugging, it points to an address "0xcccccccc" which has nothing defined... Any suggestion where the problem is?

EDIT: Forgot to post my constructor is:

```
Node(int x=0) {
    this->above=nullptr;
    this->r=x;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have a null pointer...

Comment: It's not null, it's uninitialised. Most likely at the `this->above` line.

Comment: That is what's puzzling me. Why doesn't it point to null since it was never initialized?

Comment: I'd investigate the list. First question is: Does node point to a valid element when the code enters the while loop? And then: Is the list correctly formed? Possibly, the end of the list is not really indicated by a null value but by an uninitialized variable. Make sure you set above to NULL in your constructor.

Comment: @NitroNbg: In C++, variables are not automatically initialized. If you don't set them to 0, they will have any value.

Comment: The list works exactly as intended (all the elements are in proper order, and even more important all the elements intended to be in the list are printed out in the while loop), but for some reason it goes (one step) beyond the proper elements.

Comment: Is that your only constructor?

Comment: @DerFlatulator yes that is the only constructor I wrote

Comment: Do your methods really have no return value?

Comment: No, I apologize, I ommitted the return type in the question, in my code they do return int and Node* respectively

Comment: Just realised... Why are the headers `Node::int getDiameter()` instead of `int Node::getDiameter()`? Also make sure that the Node constructor is exactly that, a constructor (`Node::Node()`), not just a function.

Comment: Is there any deletion code that could be causing access violations?

Comment: For some reason, using `this->above=nullptr` didn't work, but when I put `this->above=0` in my constructor instead it works as intended, I'll accept Roman's answer since he was the closest to the problem. Sorry for wasting your time, but this problem really irritated me. Thanks

Comment: `NULL` is simply a macro `#define NULL 0`. So our solutions are actually exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the **`uninitialized`** pointer and the **`null`** pointer in C++

```
struct node
{

};

int main()
{
    node *n1 = 0;
    node *n2;

    if(!n1)
        std::cout << "n1 points to the NULL";

    if(!n2)
        std::cout << "n2 points to the NULL";
}
```

Try to run this code and you will see that *n2 points to the NULL* won't be printed. You wonder why? That is because `n1` has been explicitly pointed to the **null**, but I wasn't done the same with `n2`. The С++ standard does not specifies what address the uninitialized pointer should hold. And there, `0xcccccccc` is seems to be the address that your compiler chosen to be default for the debug mode.

Comment: Lukily, most compilers will issue a warning if you do this. So one more reason not to ignore any compiler warning ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your constructors, set fields to NULL that are not initialised by constructor parameters, for example:

```
Node::Node(float radius) 
{
    above = NULL;
    r = radius;
}
```